# how to rotate radgrid header text in ie

Tags: html, asp.net, css, telerik-grid

i have asp.net  telerik rad grid control  i wan to rotate my header row text and display 
vertical each header cell text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this IE7 OR IE8 SUPPORTED `DEMO`

http://jsfiddle.net/fYGcV/

CSS

```
.headerText
{
display:block;
height:128px;
width:128px;
vertical-align:bottom;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="headerText">text</div>
```

OR

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/466591/Gridview-Header-Text-Vertical

Answer (score 0):

To display the text like that, consistently across all browsers, you'll need to use images. However, if you want to stick with just CSS3, you could apply this class to the header:

```
.vertical-text {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: @soheil, when you make a statement like that it doesn't really point to anything. Did you check the **applied CSS to the elements you're looking to change** to ensure its not working.

Comment: ive test  your css class with another  items not working when i was add filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); thats working in ie 7 dear friend